# Increase performance on insert cursor?

Tags: plsql, insert, cursor

I would like to ask you how would you increase the performance on Insert cursor in this code?
I need to use dynamic plsql to fetch data but dont know how to improve the INSERT in best way. like Bulk Insert maybe? 
Please let me know with code example if possible.

// This is how i use cur_handle:

```
    cur_HANDLE integer;
cur_HANDLE := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
DBMS_SQL.PARSE(cur_HANDLE, W_STMT, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS2(cur_HANDLE, W_NO_OF_COLS, W_DESC_TAB);

LOOP
-- Fetch a row   
IF DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(cur_HANDLE) > 0 THEN
    DBMS_SQL.column_value(cur_HANDLE, 9, cont_ID); 
    DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(cur_HANDLE, 3, proj_NR);    
ELSE
    EXIT;
END IF;

  Insert into w_Contracts values(counter, cont_ID, proj_NR);
counter := counter + 1;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: Why do you think you must employ dynamic SQL for the cursor?  If you want us to help you you need to explain your use case.

Comment: Becouse select statement is assembled from a website, ex if user choose to include more detailed search then the select statement is changed and the result looks different in the end. The whole application is a web site build on dinamic plsql code.

Answer (score 1):

You should do database actions in sets whenever possible, rather than row-by-row inserts. You don't tell us what `CUR_HANDLE` is, so I can't really rewrite this, but you should probably do something like:

```
INSERT INTO w_contracts
SELECT ROWNUM, cont_id, proj_nr
  FROM ( ... some table or joined tables or whatever... )
```

Though if your first value there is a primary key, it would probably be better to assign it from a sequence.

Comment: Sorry about the missing information. Here is how i use the cur_handle:

cur_HANDLE integer;  -- declaration

cur_HANDLE := dbms_sql.open_cursor;

DBMS_SQL.PARSE(cur_HANDLE, W_STMT, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS2(cur_HANDLE, W_NO_OF_COLS, W_DESC_TAB);

Comment: But what's the select statement for the cursor?

Comment: W_STMT is the name of statement variable.

Comment: Obviously, but what is the statement?

Comment: I dont have tables or joined tables, all I want to use is cont_ID and proj_NR from the loop and insert it with bulk insert!

Comment: You have a select statement defined somewhere, that's what your cursor is based on and what your loop is looping over.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6963/discussion-between-haris-and-eaolson)

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1) You can populate inside the loop a PL/SQL array and then just after the loop insert the whole array in one step using:

```
FORALL i in contracts_tab.first .. contracts_tab.last
  INSERT INTO w_contracts VALUES contracts_tab(i);
```

Solution 2) if the v_stmt contains a valid SQL statement you can directly insert data into the table using

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO w_contracts (counter, cont_id, proj_nr) 
    SELECT rownum, 9, 3 FROM ('||v_stmt||')';
```

Comment: Inside of the existing Loop ? I am afraid it will make the whole operation slower becouse it does the Insert for every row it fetch!

Answer (score 0):

> "select statement is assembled from a website, ex if user choose to
>   include more detailed search then the select statement is changed and
>   the result looks different in the end. The whole application is a web
>   site build on dinamic plsql code."

This is a dangerous proposition, because it opens your database to SQL injection.  This is the scenario in which Bad People subvert your parameters to expand the data they can retrieve or to escalate privileges.  At the very least you need to be using DBMS_ASSERT to validate user input.  [Find out more](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dbms_assert_10gR2.php).

Of course, if you are allowing users to pass whole SQL strings (you haven't provided any information regarding the construction of `W_STMT`) then all bets are off.  DBMS_ASSERT won't help you there.

Anyway, as you have failed to give the additional information we actually need, please let me spell it out for you:

- will the SELECT statement always have the same column names from the same table name, or can the user change those two?
- will you always be interested in the third and ninth columns?
- how is the `W_STMT` string assembled?  How much control do you have over its projection?