# Bulk insert from Array to table PLSQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, insert

Does anyone know if its possible to use Bulk insert from following code:

```
   FORALL I IN IBT_KONTIDS.FIRST .. IBT_KONTIDS.LAST
   INSERT INTO EX_TABLE VALUES (IBT_KONTIDS(I), IBT_PROJNUMS(I), CURRENTUSER, SYSDATE);
```

What I am trying to achieeve is a fast insert into EX_TABLE from my 2 arrays and additional parameters like userinfo and current time. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Um, that code *is* a bulk insert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think so. But, even if you could why would you want to? You're asking for more trouble than I could possibly name. What happens if your two arrays don't have the same number of records in them? What happens if they were collected into the array in a different order?

Why not just use a join collect everything into 1 cursor and then insert that?

```
SQL>
SQL> create table blah as
  2   select a.*
  3        , cast( null as varchar2(30) ) as usr
  4        , cast( null as date ) as dt
  5        , cast( null as varchar2(30) ) as object_name
  6     from user_tables a
  7    where 1 = 0;

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> declare
  2
  3    cursor c_tab is
  4     select a.*, user, sysdate, b.object_name
  5       from user_tables a
  6       join user_objects b
  7         on a.table_name = b.object_name
  8            ;
  9
 10    type t__tab is table of c_tab%rowtype index by binary_integer;
 11    t_tab t__tab;
 12
 13  begin
 14
 15     open c_tab;
 16
 17     loop
 18       fetch c_tab bulk collect
 19        into t_tab limit 1000;
 20
 21       exit when t_tab.count = 0;
 22
 23       forall ii in t_tab.first .. t_tab.last
 24         insert into blah
 25         values t_tab(ii)
 26                ;
 27
 28       commit;
 29
 30     end loop;
 31
 32     close c_tab;
 33
 34  end;
 35  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Great info Ben but its not exactly what I was looking for, If you can take a look on my previous post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8962875/increase-performance-on-insert-cursor) you'll se that i use dynamic sql in a loop to fetch data and fill my arrays. I want to avoid a one-row-by-row inserting into a table. Instead I filled my arrays which i was planned to use as a insert-bulk to destination table. Dont know if this is the right way to do it?

Comment: @Haris, that's the beauty of `bulk collect ... forall` it doesn't do the insert row by row. There is only one DML operation, one of the reasons for the hefty increase in performance. It might be possible to create a rowtype of a `ref_cursor` - I've never tried, in which case `bulk collect` will still work but it seems like you're going down a very complicated route. Does it really have to be dynamic?

Comment: You are right Ben, i tottaly agree with you, I dont have much choice regarding the dynamic plsql becouse the code is already written by somebody else in that way, its a bit complicated. I am only trying to solve the insert problem. The real problem occurs when there is a plenty data to insert becouse the loop performs a single-row-insert every time.

Comment: at least in Oracle 10g that I am using, probably parentheses are required after VALUES : insert into blah values (t_tab(ii));

Comment: That definitely stirs a memory @hello and this answer would have been executed against a 11g database in 2012. I would more strongly suggest against forall today in favour of a simple insert statement - no cursor, no loops, no PL/SQL, just an insert stament -  if that's at all possible.